# jquery Get UL innerhtml

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the innerhtml of the UL after clicking on a li, any ideas?

This is what i have so far which gets the innerhtml of the li.

```
 $('#Modbutton').click(function() {       

      var litype = document.getElementById('Modbutton').innerHTML;
      alert (litype);

   });
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be PHP relevant..

Comment: `I'm trying to get the innerhtml of the UL after clicking on a li,` it means it is many and **ID should be unique** use class instead and use `.closest('ul')` with `.html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is using `closest`

```
 $('#Modbutton').click(function() {       

      alert($(this).closest('ul').html())
   });
```

API Documentation Ref https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select inner HTML of the `ul` that is the parent of the clicked `li`:

```
$('#Modbutton').click(function() {       
    var litype = $(this).parent().html();
    alert (litype);
});
```